# Efficient Implementation of LDAP Query (using JNDI)

Tags: ldap, jndi

I am writing a LDAP Query program using JNDI, that will pull one or more attributes, in any combination, from 100s of records.

I am tempted to pull them all and then weed out the ones specified, because I am not sure about how to create a filter based on all the possible combinations of user-input.

I might still figure out this latter implementation,  but my question is this:

Is there serious overhead with pulling all attributes at once?    Enough that justifies this as not the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Only request the attributes required. Use the mostly tightly scoped search that is possible.